How do I make a POST request from Dash app to save data to a table in Azure Databricks?
I have built a web application using Python Dash and I have a database and table set up in Databricks. I now want to submit and make a POST request to Databricks to save data from the UI. I was able to establish a connection to Databricks and make a fetch request, but not POST. How do I do that?
I have made a class in file databricks_connection.py:
#%%
import pandas as pd
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#%%

class DatabricksConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = os.environ.get("SERVER_NAME")
        self.http_path = os.environ.get("HTTP_PATH")
        self.client_id = os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID")
        self.client_secret = os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET")
        self.connection = None
    


    def connect(self):
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    def query(self, query_string, chunk_size=None):
        if not hasattr(self, 'spark'):
            from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
            self.spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        results = self.spark.sql(query_string)
        results = results.toPandas()
        return results

And this is where I used the connection data.py:
#%%
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
from databricks_connection import DatabricksConnection as conn

#%%
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Databricks = conn.DatabricksConnection()
        self.Databricks.connect()

    def _load_query(self, query_file):
        with open(query_file, 'r') as file:
            return file.read()

    def _format_query(self, query_template, **kwargs):
        return query_template.format(**kwargs)

    def fetch_data(self, query_file, execute = True, **kwargs):
        query_template = self._load_query(os.path.join(self.queries_dir, query_file))
        query_string = self._format_query(query_template, **kwargs)
        self.last_query_string = query_string
        if execute:
            return self.Databricks.query(query_string)
        else:
            return query_string

data = data()        
def test(parameter):
    return data.fetch_data('query.sql', parameter=parameter)


I think you can do it with the REST api but as far as I know, you can only upload to dbfs. I would suggest looking into the databricks sdk. You can upload your files to volume like so:
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient


class DatabricksConnection:
    _client = None

    def __init__(self, DATABRICKS_TOKEN: str, DATABRICKS_HOST: str) -> None:
        self.init_client(DATABRICKS_TOKEN, DATABRICKS_HOST)

    def init_client(self, DATABRICKS_TOKEN: str, DATABRICKS_HOST: str):
        if DatabricksConnection._client is not None:
            return DatabricksConnection._client
        try:
            DatabricksConnection._client = WorkspaceClient(token=DATABRICKS_TOKEN, host=DATABRICKS_HOST)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Error while creating Databricks client: {e}")


    def upload_file(self, file_path: str, content: str):
        self._client.files.upload(file_path, content)

conn = DatabricksConnection(DATABRICKS_TOKEN, DATABRICKS_HOST)
conn.upload_file(...)

Make sure you find out the correct path of the table you want to write to.
